# About RecycleView

Tags: android, json, hosting, stickyrecycleview

I want to display data from a database that has been hosted into recycleview by using json.I've tried various ways to make it. Can someone give me a link a tutorial on:
1. Displays data of type mediumblob into json.
2. Displays data from the database that has been hosted into recycleview.
3. Displays info window about the data that is clicked from recycleview. I'm a beginner and can only rely on tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, u have to create an adapter extending RecyclerView.Adapter class and a ViewHolder, extending RecyclerView.ViewHolder. Adapter and ViewHolder controls how your data will be displayed in RecyclerView. The best examples are in official Google docs on https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html?hl=en
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html